# How to display a m3u8 URL video in amp-video

Tags: javascript, amp-html, http-live-streaming

In AMP, I am unable to properly display m3u8 videos.

Here is the code before the AMP transformation:

https://pastebin.com/RAAWReyB

And after I get:

```
<amp-video ...>
<video>
<source type="application/vnd.apple.mpegurl" src="https://something/video.hls">
</amp-video>
```

Comment: Is that the right link? `<amp-video>` does not appear at all in the source.

Comment: The source code in the link is before the amp transformation. Then I convert it to <amp-video ..> <video ..> <source type= src=> like you commented on github.

Comment: To debug effectively we need to see the raw AMP source, something like https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-video/source/ that includes `<amp-video>` elements in the raw HTML. The details of the transformation itself don't matter.

Comment: You mean this? https://prnt.sc/hxjs8z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following can be used to display HLS video in AMP:

```
<amp-video width="480"
  height="270"
  poster="/img/tokyo.jpg"
  layout="responsive"
  controls
  autoplay>
  <div fallback>
    <p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- displayed if HLS is supported -->
  <source type="application/vnd.apple.mpegurl" src="/video/tokyo.m3u8">
  <!-- displayed if HLS is not supported -->
  <source type="video/mp4" src="/video/tokyo-no-hls.mp4">
</amp-video>
```

For more information, see the [annotated demo](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-video/) ([simplified version](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-video/source/)).

Answer (score 1):

Safari might be the only one that supports (amp-video & amp-ima-video) hls (.m3u8 video extensions) natively.
I tested with

- Chrome v67.0.3396.99
- Firefox v61.0.1
- Safari v11.1.1

You can check if your browser supports the hls here:
https://codepen.io/kenanbalija/pen/GBgmxG

```
...
<amp-video width="480" height="270" 
         layout="fixed"
         controls>

<source type="application/vnd.apple.mpegURL" src="https://video-dev.github.io/streams/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8">
<source type="video/webm" src="https://ampbyexample.com/video/tokyo.webm">
```

(not my custom codepen, i forgot where i forked this from)